# QGIS 3 Geopackage - different attributes to same polygon

Tags: qgis-3

I've got a geopackage with one set of polygons and an attribute table with lots of fields  - I have calculated a lot of them with reference to each other. They concern three different types of commercial property: retail, industrial and office. As they are, the attribute table is a pain to use. I'd like to split it up into 3 different objects. I could do this just by creating 3 identical polygon datasets with 3 different attribute tables, but this seems inefficient. Is there a way that I can save the data so that a single polygon dataset can relate to 3 different attribute tables - similar to structuring related tables in a database?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Geopackage is awesome like that! It's just SQLite.

You could separate the attributes from the polygons by using separate tables where each row had an identifier mapping to its polygon.

QGIS will then prompt you to select the tables to load when you load the file.

Then you can use the Joins feature to specify which table you want to join to its geometries at any given point.

Strictly speaking you should use the officially specified http://www.geopackage.org/spec/#attributes for this but if you are not distributing the file further it should be fine.